"Deadline" error when embedding video with Google Vertex AI multimodal embedding modal
I am currently using Vertex AI's Multimodal Embedding Model (https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/embeddings/get-multimodal-embeddings)
I was able to get the Image and Text examples running just fine using the Python SDK and POST, however, when I try to run the following Video example (from the above link), I get the following error
    import vertexai
    
    from vertexai.vision_models import MultiModalEmbeddingModel, Video
    
    project_id = 'project_name'
    location = 'us-central1'
    
    vertexai.init(project=project_id, location=location)
    
    # Document metadata
    video_path = 'gs://test-public-bucket-123/dog_jumping_short.mp4' # public small 1 MB 7 second video file
    description = 'dogs jumping'
    
    model = MultiModalEmbeddingModel.from_pretrained("multimodalembedding@001")
    
    video = Video.load_from_file(video_path)
    
    embeddings = model.get_embeddings(
        video=video
    )
    
    # Video Embeddings are segmented based on the video_segment_config.
    print("Video Embeddings:")
    for video_embedding in embeddings.video_embeddings:
        print(
            f"Video Segment: {video_embedding.start_offset_sec} - {video_embedding.end_offset_sec}"
        )
        print(f"Embedding: {video_embedding.embedding}")
    
    print(f"Text Embedding: {embeddings.text_embedding}")

The error I get when running this sample code is related to Deadline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Code/multi-modal-test/multi-modal/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 76, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Code/multi-modal-test/multi-modal/lib/python3.12/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1181, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Code/multi-modal-test/multi-modal/lib/python3.12/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1006, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAUTHENTICATED
        details = "Video embedding failed with the following error: Deadline"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.81.234:443 {grpc_message:"Video embedding failed with the following error: Deadline", grpc_status:16, created_time:"2024-05-23T15:53:15.429704-04:00"}"

Note that I have been able to embed contextual_text and image just fine with the same authentication, so I am fairly certain this has nothing to do with authentication even though the error says so.
I have also tried to POST using the following cURL, but I get the same error response Deadline
    curl -X POST \ 
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     -d @request.json \
     "https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/multi/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/multimodalembedding@001:predict"

I have the following APIs enabled (note that according to docs, I only need to have Vertex AI API enabled)

These are my IAM permissions
- members:
  - user:me@gmail.com
  role: roles/aiplatform.admin
- members:
  - user:me@gmail.com
  role: roles/aiplatform.user
- members:
  - user:me@gmail.com
  role: roles/ml.admin
- members:
  - user:me@gmail.com
  role: roles/owner
- members:
  - user:me@gmail.com
  role: roles/storage.admin
- members:
  - user:me@gmail.com
  role: roles/visionai.admin
etag: BwYaJsGtzOk=
version: 1

I am not using a Service Account, but a User Account.
Anyone know what I can do here?

This might come from a discrepancy between the "current project" of gcloud, and the "Application Defaults Credentials". This can be confusing because the exact order of these commands matter.
To make sure, could you try in this order:
1.
gcloud config set project MY_PROJECT_ID

(doc)
2.
gcloud auth application-default login

(doc)

Run your python program (or your cuRL command)


Looks like this discovered that I did not enable the Service Usage API (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/serviceusage.googleapis.com/metrics) where it prompts me to enable it when running gcloud auth application-default login. However, after enabling it (and waiting a few minutes), it still gives me the same error. I see in our email correspondence that the endpoint works for you -- must be a permission issue on my end then

After waiting an hour or so, it seems to have worked. THANK YOU!

For context for others, ADC is https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc

All of the code looks right. This could be a service issue or something to do with the file on GCS.
Does this error occur on any video that's sent to the Multimodal embeddings API from your project, or just this particular one? Can you try using this video in a public GCS bucket gs://cloud-samples-data/video/animals.mp4.

Hey Holt! Happy to hear your reply. I get the following response back when running gsutil ls ...: gs://multi-modal-assets/videos/sample/dog_jumping_short.mp4 which indicates it is able to find the file when authenticated

I am also trying this public video URL to embed: https://storage.googleapis.com/test-public-bucket-123/dog_jumping_short.mp4, and I am still getting the same error.

Possibly not the root cause, but can you run this to make sure the object exists in GCS?
gsutil ls gs://multi-assets/videos/dog_jumping_short.mp4

When I do this with my own account, I get BucketNotFoundException: 404 gs://multi-assets bucket does not exist. while I was expecting something like AccessDeniedException: 403 does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

I tried this, and it continues to give me the same error. I also tried a public bucket + public file, and it also continues to give me the same problem :/ gs://test-public-bucket-123/dog_jumping_short.mp4

I could successfully run your script, replacing project_id with a project I own, and video_path with the public resource gs://test-public-bucket-123/dog_jumping_short.mp4

Huh! Maybe it's my project setting that's causing issues then? I am using an enterprise account (under my company), so that may be the problem then!

I tried it also on my personal account, and still got the same error. Do you mind sharing maybe what your permissions look like? Maybe it's a configuration, permissions, or an API that I didn't enable?

It's because the server doesn't have the same access permission as the client.
video = Video.load_from_file(video_path) doesn't really read the video when the video_path is a gsUri. It records the uri instead. The server then reads from the uri and fails due to access permission.
Reading video bytes on the client side avoids this problem:
with open(local_video, 'rb') as f:
  video = Video(video_bytes=f.read)

